# Issues with updating a JPA entity from a Spring mvc controller method and using hidden input fields to store an ID

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Say I have an **entity/javabean** that has a **substantial number of properties**.

Furthermore, I have a html form (in jsp or thymeleaf) that I use to update that entity.

As my application stands here is how I proceed to update the entity:

1. I set the JPA ID of the entity in a hidden html field in the form
2. in the Spring controller, I retrieve the entity from the database using that hidden ID
3. still in the controller method I then set each field of the previously retrieved entity using the fields of the spring mvc ModelAttribute passed as an argument to the controller method.
4. I then persist/update the entity using the entityManager.

Here is a sample from my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/family/advertisement/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String editFamilyAdvertisement(@ModelAttribute @Validated(value = Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class) FamilyAdvertisement familyAdvertisement,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        FamilyAdvertisement advertisementForUpdate = advertisementService.findFamilyAdvertisement(familyAdvertisement.getId());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateModel(model, familyAdvertisement);
            return "family/advertisement/edit";
        }
        advertisementForUpdate.setNeeds(familyAdvertisement.getNeeds());
        advertisementForUpdate.setChildcareTypes(familyAdvertisement.getChildcareTypes());
        advertisementForUpdate.setDayToTimeSlots(familyAdvertisement.getDayToTimeSlots());
        ...
        advertisementService.editFamilyAdvertisement(advertisementForUpdate);
        return "redirect:/some/url";
    }
```

I have two problems with the application as it currently stands:

- Firstly a clever hacker can easily tamper with the ID and update someone else's advertisement.
- Secondly, I have to update each field of the attached entity manually using those from the spring mvc model attribute: this is tedious and ugly.

Can anyone please suggest a better pattern or solution?

**edit 1**: I followed the provided advice.

Here is my modified controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/family/advertisement/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String editFamilyAdvertisement(@ModelAttribute @Validated(value = Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class) FamilyAdvertisementInfo familyAdvertisementInfo,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        Member member = memberService.retrieveCurrentMember();
        FamilyAdvertisement advertisementForCheck = advertisementService.findFamilyAdvertisement(familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement().getId());
        if (!member.getAdvertisements().contains(advertisementForCheck)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("advertisement does not belong to member");
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateModel(model, familyAdvertisementInfo);
            return "family/advertisement/edit";
        }
        advertisementService.editFamilyAdvertisement(familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement());
        return "redirect:/family/advertisement/edit/" + familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement().getId();
    }
```

You see that I have to fetch the Family advertisement entity from db in order to check it belongs to the current member in session. Then when I try to save the entity as advised I get a **StaleObjectStateException** as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [bignibou] in context with path [/bignibou] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bignibou.domain.FamilyAdvertisement#1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bignibou.domain.FamilyAdvertisement#1]] with root cause
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bignibou.domain.FamilyAdvertisement#1]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:345)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocatio
```

**edit 2**: the issue I have if I don't fetch the entity from the db, is that the above call  to `contains` is always going to evaluate to `false` because it uses the `equals` method internally and the entity may have changed (after all that's the purpose of the method).

```
if (!member.getAdvertisements().contains(familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("advertisement does not belong to member");
        }
```

**edit 3**:

I still have the same issue with the StaleObjectStateException because it seems that my controller method does two saves/transactions.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/family/advertisement/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
    public String editFamilyAdvertisement(@ModelAttribute @Validated(value = Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class) FamilyAdvertisementInfo familyAdvertisementInfo,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        Member member = memberService.retrieveCurrentMember();//ONE
        if (!advertisementService.advertisementBelongsToMember(familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement(), member)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("advertisement does not belong to member");
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateModel(model, familyAdvertisementInfo);
            return "family/advertisement/edit";
        }
        familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement().setMember(member);
        advertisementService.editFamilyAdvertisement(familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement());//TWO
        return "redirect:/family/advertisement/edit/" + familyAdvertisementInfo.getFamilyAdvertisement().getId();
    }
```

See exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.bignibou.domain.FamilyAdvertisement#1]
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:903)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:891)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.merge(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.merge(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:345)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:334)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:91)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.save(Unknown Source)
    com.bignibou.service.AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service.ajc$interMethod$com_bignibou_service_AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service$com_bignibou_service_AdvertisementServiceImpl$updateFamilyAdvertisement(AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service.aj:58)
    com.bignibou.service.AdvertisementServiceImpl.updateFamilyAdvertisement(AdvertisementServiceImpl.java:1)
    com.bignibou.service.AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_bignibou_service_AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service$com_bignibou_service_AdvertisementServiceImpl$updateFamilyAdvertisement(AdvertisementServiceImpl_Roo_Service.aj)
    com.bignibou.service.AdvertisementServiceImpl.editFamilyAdvertisement(AdvertisementServiceImpl.java:27)
    com.bignibou.controller.AdvertisementController.editFamilyAdvertisement(AdvertisementController.java:85)
```

Comment: Did you override the hashCode()/equals() methods? Maybe they should only use the id.

Comment: Using only the ID in hashcode/equals is not really recommended...

Comment: Why is it not recommended? It seems to make sense in this case. But if that's a problem, then instead of calling contains() you can compare the IDs one by one.

Comment: See my edit #3. The `advertisementBelongsToMember` method does the comparison one by one...

Comment: What does the editFamilyAdvertisement do? I think you should ask another question since it is not releted to your first questions.

Comment: You're right. That's what I have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795819/preventing-the-hibernate-staleobjectstateexception-from-occurring). I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: You could also add the id field as a path variable like so `@RequestMapping(value = "/family/advertisement/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html") public String editFamilyAdvertisement(@PathVariable Integer id, @ModelAttribute @Validated(value = Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class) FamilyAdvertisementInfo familyAdvertisementInfo, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)`. From there you can set the id of your entity in the controller to guarantee they are not hacking another id. A lot of boilerplate code but works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First question: when you retrieve the entity from the database, specify the id *and* the user. If no entity is found with the id and the user, it means that the user doesn't own the entity.

Second question: several solutions, depending of your requierements

- Expose your entity directly instead of a dedicated form object
- Encapsulate your entity in the form and use delegate methods (your IDE can generate them)
- Use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Hi WilQu. Thanks for the reply. Good point regarding the first question! Now regarding the second question, I already expose the entity directly but the object coming from the controller model attribute is detached so I still need to update each field as explained in my post... Do you see my point?

Comment: By the way, Dozer looks nice, but I'd rather not introduce another dependency if possible.

Comment: @balteo why not just reattach it then?

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. I am editing my post accordingly.

Comment: If your entity inherits from an abstract class and contains an id field in the abstract class you can create a method to wrap the `entityManager.merge` which first does a

`Object ref = this.entityManager.find(persistentClass, entity.getId()); if (ref != null) { BeanUtils.copyProperties(entity, ref);}`
You can skip the copying of the id field in the `BeanUtils.copyProperties` by passing in ignored fields.

Comment: Hi Dukethrash: I have actually used BeanUtils.copyProperties. I just forgot to add a comment here or update the post... Thanks a lot.